# Stripe - how add connected account on the subscription (application fee amount)?

Tags: c#, .net, stripe-payments, payment

I try add subscription method to my project where customer can subscription product from other user. But i have problem because when i use it:

```
LineItems = new List<SessionLineItemOptions>
  {
    new SessionLineItemOptions
    {
      Price = "{{PRICE_ID}}",
      Quantity = 1,
    },
  },
  Mode = "subscription",
  SuccessUrl = "https://example.com/success",
  CancelUrl = "https://example.com/cancel",
  PaymentIntentData = new SessionPaymentIntentDataOptions
  {
    ApplicationFeeAmount = 123,
  },
};

var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
{
  StripeAccount = "{{CONNECTED_ACCOUNT_ID}}",
};
var service = new SessionService();
Session session = service.Create(options, requestOptions);
```

But I have error „You can not pass `payment_intent_data` in `subscription` mode".
Can i add application fee amount with linked account to subscription? Is payment usually the only option?

PS. I create my product like this:

```
var options = new ProductCreateOptions
                {
                    Name = "new product",
                    DefaultPriceData = new ProductDefaultPriceDataOptions
                    {
                        UnitAmount = price,
                        Currency = "pln"
                    },
                    Expand = new List<string> { "default_price" }
                };
                var requestOptions = new RequestOptions
                {
                    StripeAccount = stripeAccountId,
                };
                _productService.Create(options, requestOptions);
```

Answer (score 1):

You'd use https://stripe.com/docs/api/checkout/sessions/create#create_checkout_session-subscription_data-application_fee_percent instead.

```
var options = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionCreateOptions
{
...
   SubscriptionData = new Stripe.Checkout.SessionSubscriptionDataOptions
   {
      ApplicationFeePercent = 10
   },
};
...
```

Comment: Thank you. But now i have error "You must provide at least one recurring price in `subscription` mode when using prices.". How to set it on my api side?

Comment: I have given the process of creating the product above.

Comment: https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/manage-prices?dashboard-or-api=api#create-price